# Print items in PriorityQueue class without modifying it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print all of the items that are in a queue.PriorityQueue class without modifying it. I do not care about the order in which they print.

It doesn't seem to have a __str__ or __repr__ function implemented.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
q = PriorityQueue()
print(q)
```

just prints the object address, like "<queue.PriorityQueue object at 0x7face64f10d0>"

```
print(list(q))
```

causes "TypeError: 'PriorityQueue' object is not iterable", because it is not iterable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over or print the items in the queue by accessing the underlying .queue object:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
q = PriorityQueue()
print(q.queue)
```

This is implementation-dependent, so may not work on non-vanilla python implementations, or may be broken by future changes.

Comment: He mentions that he doesn't want to modify the Queue

Comment: I don't think this modifies the queue. PriorityQueue.queue is just a list, so accessing and printing it should not do that: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/queue.py